# Accessing the Sandboxed Apple Store without XCode

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, mac-app-store, ccl

I am working on an OSX app which is created using an open source common lisp implementation called CCL.  We are trying to add in app purchases to our app and I just read through the StoreKitGuide and I am wondering how will I be able to test the in app purchases without using XCode.
The documentation gives instructions about accessing the sandboxed app store using XCode:

> When you launch your application from Xcode, Store Kit does not connect to the App Store. Instead, it connects
>   to a special sandbox store environment. The sandbox environment uses the infrastructure of the App Store,
>   but it does not process actual payments.

But it doesn't tell you how this could be done without xcode.  What can be done test in app purchases without XCode?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference whether you launch with Xcode or not.   Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I had just read through the documentation and it seemed to me that there was no way to test it without XCode. I am still working on getting it ready. But if you think it will work that's great news. Thank you!